# Process error emails - not receiving them in WInter 16

Tags: email, process-builder, process

I am trying to debug my Process (created before Winter 16 was applied) but I am no longer receiving error emails when the Process encounters an email.  The log message for this one is useless at all levels of the debugger so that is of now help. I am the last user to modify the Process and I deactivated it then reactivated it today.

Winter 16 was applied over the weekend so I assume this is the cause.  Was there anything released with Winter 16 that could stop these errors from being sent to me?

Comment: Check Administer -> Email Administration -> Deliverability and make sure "All email" selected for Access level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I confirmed that value was set before posting this question.

Comment: There is a new option in Winter 16. Go to Administer -> Email Administration -> Apex Exception Email. I've tested it today and received bunch of flow exception emails.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that.  I added my user to the list (and confirmed my email is correct) but I'm still not receiving the error emails.

Comment: If you are not the person who create the process, check with the person who create it. He / She may got the emails.

Comment: I created it, am the last person to update the Process and last person to activate it.